# Distinguishing Legitimate Anomalies From True Anomalies

Tags: anomaly-detection

In order to detect anomalous user commands, I am using a One Class SVM (OCSVM). First, I build a OCSVM model over normal commands of the user. Then, upon receiving a new command, the model either output +1 for normal commands, and -1 for abnormal ones.

However, after a while, the user may change his behavior. Consequently, new legitimate commands will be considered as abnormal (i.e., false alarms) as they do not conform to previous user behavior.

**How can my OCSVM model autonomously adapt to legitimate user behavior change?**

**More specifically, How can I distinguish between a true anomaly from a false anomaly ?** since I am not sure for a new command, considered as abnormal, if it is really abnormal or it belongs to the legitimate user changing his behavior.

I am finding many related concepts such as Incremental and Online Learning, but I think those can be used to retrain the model only when we are sure about the label of a new instance (a new command in my case).

Comment: This problem seems to belong to the general domain of learning in dynamical environments, where the far past is not an accurate representation of the present and future. Right?  If so, I provide a full answer. For now, you can try oversampling more/undersampling less recent data before training your SVM. These two links can also be also relevant and helpful:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305369282/download

Comment: I appreciate you comment, but i don't understand what do you mean, and the link is inaccessible (page not found)

Comment: https://repositorio.inesctec.pt/bitstream/123456789/5341/1/P-00K-VEY.pdf

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicates: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/38171/924